# Keep zeros after removing a period from a number using php

Tags: php, str-replace

When I use the PHP str_replace to remove a period in a string it removes the zeros after the string as well for example

```
100.00
```

turns to

```
100
```

But I want

```
10000
```

Here is my code below

```
function remove_periods($string){
    $string = str_replace('.', '', $string);

    return $string;
}
```

Comment: That's not what the code does. Are you perhaps mistaken about `100.00` being a string?

Comment: sorry i meant to say float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are a few ways to adjust your code.

Here's just one: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZFjPb))

```
function remove_periods($float){
    return $float * 100;
}

echo remove_periods((float)100.00); // 10000
echo remove_periods((string)100.00); // 10000
```

and another:

```
function remove_periods($float){
    return number_format($float, 2, '', '');
}
```

Comment: If your input may have more or less decimal places, please clarify your question.